# Arduino Wifi Shield is not communicating

Tags: arduino

My project is an Arduino RC car controlled with Android.  For that I bought the Arduino Uno R3 and the [Arduino WiFi shield](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoWiFiShield). The problem is that the wifiShield not listening to the client and can't receive data. I don't know how to solve the problem, and cannot setup a connection between the devices.

Arduino Code:

```
char ssid[] = "***";         
char pass[] = "***";   
int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;

WiFiServer server(1991);


boolean alreadyConnected = false; 

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("Attempting to connect to WPA network...");
    Serial.print("SSID: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);

    status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
    if ( status != WL_CONNECTED) { 
        Serial.println("Couldn't get a wifi connection");
        while(true);
    } 
    else {
        server.begin();
        server.status();
        Serial.print("Connected to wifi. My address:");
        IPAddress myAddress = WiFi.localIP();
        IPAddress inetAddress=WiFi.gatewayIP();
        Serial.println( myAddress);

        Serial.println("Inet: ");
        Serial.println(inetAddress);
    }
}

void loop() {

    WiFiClient client = server.available();

    if(client) {
        if (!alreadyConnected) {

            client.flush();    
            Serial.println("We have a new client");
            client.println("Hello, client!"); 
            alreadyConnected = true;
        } 

        if (client.available() > 0) {
            // read the bytes incoming from the client:
            char thisChar = client.read();
            // echo the bytes back to the client:
            server.write(thisChar);
            // echo the bytes to the server as well:
            Serial.write(thisChar);
        }
    }
}
```

What might cause my problems and how can I solve them?

Comment: What is the output you see? What status messages does it print? And why the infinite loop on a failure to connect?

Answer (score 3):

Had this EXACT same issue.  Make sure you're using Arduino 1.0.3 instead of 1.0.5, that's what did it for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I can just confirm that working with Arduino IDE 1.0.5 WiFi shield will not work. With 1.0.3 it work just fine.